# Laravel AJAX PUT does not receive data

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6.33 and when wanting to send the information with the method **PUT** it is impossible for me, the update function does not receive anything.

this is my javascript:

```
$("#SaveArea").on("click",function(e){

            event.preventDefault();



            var token = $("#token").val();

            $.ajax({

                url: "/areas/{{ $area->AreaID }}",
                headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},

                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: {"name":"alex"},
                type: 'put',

                beforeSend: function () {
                    // alert("akus")
                },
                success: function (response) {

                    console.log(response)
                    // swal(response['mensaje'],'', "success");

                }
            });

  });
```

form data:

```
<form class="form-group" method="POST" action="/areas/{{ $area->AreaID }}" autocomplete="off" id="FormArea">
    @method('PUT')

    @csrf
```

update function:

```
public function update(Request $request, Area $area)
{

    return $request->all() ;
```

web.php

```
// Areas
Route::resource('/areas','AreasController');
Route::post('/areas/store','AreasController@store');
Route::get('/areas','AreasController@getAreas');
Route::get('/area/new',function(){
return view("rrh.new_area");});
```

Comment: Sorry but this is an English Langusge site. You could try on `https://es.stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: Check the Network tab in your developer console, and verify that it's submitted as PUT and that it's sending the data you expect.

Comment: why are you setting contentType and processData to false? what happends if you delete those lines?

Comment: Remove `contentType: false, processData: false,` and change `event` to `e` since you are calling it in your click function as `e`

Comment: @AfrazAhmad wow, you are a genius, a lot thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**type can only be GET or POST**

Remove **contentType: false, processData: false**

Change: **event to e**